# Limit connections per second with iptables/ufw

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, ufw

How can I tweak the following entries to allow more requests per second? Maximum hitcount is 20 if you do not edit some other config files.

The entry of my /etc/ufw/before.rules file

```
-A ufw-before-input -p udp --dport 53 -m recent --name dnslimit --set
-A ufw-before-input -p udp --dport 53 -m recent --name dnslimit --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 20 -j DROP
```

I would like to allow like 50 DNS requests per second.

Using Ubuntu 14.04 Server with UFW.

Comment: See `connlimit` description in `iptables` manual page.